# Оставить только часто встречающиеся значения Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Есть исходный DataFrame:

```
St  Rt
1   23
1   3
1   3
1   4
2   4
2   5
2   5
3   7
3   7
```

Нужно оставить только те значения из `St`, которые чаще встречаются, например, 3 и более раз. То есть на выходе надо получить такое:

```
St  Rt
1   23
1   3
1   3
1   4
2   4
2   5
2   5
```

Comment: Данный ресурс не предназначен для решения домашних заданий и/или лабораторных работ. Приводи свое решение, что именно не работает, с каким текстом ошибки, а мы подскажем, в чем твоя ошибка. Иначе обращайся к фрилансерам

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

```
In [36]: df.groupby("St").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
Out[36]:
   St  Rt
0   1  23
1   1   3
2   1   3
3   1   4
4   2   4
5   2   5
6   2   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'st': [1, 1, 1, 2], 'Value': [100, 150, 50, 50]})
df['Counts'] = df['st'].map(df['st'].value_counts())
print(df.loc[df['Counts'] >= 3])
```